# Are both sentences true?

Tags: grammar

1. The bear is dangerous, you had better not come near it.
2. The bear is dangerous, you had better not **to** come near it.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the oddity of using diacritical marks in English, the first sentence is grammatical whereas the second is not.

"Had better not" is an idiomatic phrase that acts like a "modal verb" synonymous with "ought not." The complement of a modal verb is a bare infinitive. Therefor "to come" is wrong grammatically whereas "come" is correct grammatically. Idiomatically, however, "go" is more natural than "come" because it implies intentionality.

I want to thank all the commenters for making me see that my original explanation for **why** the second sentence was wrong was just plain silly.

Comment: Re *English does not insert a "to" in front of the verb in a sentence.* That wouldn't be the case with the alternative phrasing *It's better not **to** go near it.*

Comment: @FF But in your alternative sentence the verb is "is" and "come" is an infinitive. I actually thought about distinguishing such cases in my answer, but decided that doing so would confuse rather than clarify things. We would not say "It to is better not to come."

Comment: Yeah, I know my example is slightly different. But OP's ***come*** (switched to more idiomatic ***go*** in my version) is still an infinitive. It's just that we use ***unmarked*** infinitives (without ***to***) after certain "main" verbs, as in *You **mustn't / shouldn't / had better not...*** But we *don't* do that with other verbs *(You **don't need to** do that, I **have to** do it, He **wants** to do it)*.

Comment: @FF If you want to define "better not" as a modal verb, then I agree with your analysis. Otherwise, the only verb present is "come." It is silly to argue about definitions. If we define "better not" as a modal verb, then "come" is an infinitive required to be bare. If we do not define "better not" as a modal verb, then "come" is the required verb in the sentence and required not to be preceded by "to." We get to the same place by analyzing from different definitions. I prefer not to talk about modals if possible because learners find them difficult.

Comment: The first sentence of your answer is correct. The explanation is incorrect. Consider the sentence *The dog is hungry. You ought to feed it.* We put a *to* in front of *feed*. (And *ought* is usually considered an auxiliary verb here, just like *had* in the OP's sentence.)

Comment: Only someone who was themselves near the bear would say "don't **come** near the bear"; everyone else would say "don't **go** near the bear".

Comment: @PeterShor: Seeing your example there, my first thought was "I can just about get my head around a bare infinitive there" *(You ought feed it)*. It just sounds a bit "dated, formal". On the other hand, with *He maketh / makes me [**to**] lie down in green pastures* it's more dated / antiquated to *include* the infinitive marker, so there doesn't seem to be much consistency about where infinitive markers are headed. Anyway, it's not only auxiliaries that can dispense with the word ***to*** - *I demand [that] it **stop***, for example, is a bare infinitive with no auxiliary.

Comment: Upon reflection and reading all the comments now several times, I realize that "had better not" is an idiom that does act as a modal verb synonymous with "ought not" and that my answer is just plain wrong. I apologize to all for not recognizing and acknowledging the error more quickly. I shall edit my answer appropriately.